# Prove that a group $G$ given by generators and relations has $|G|=8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $G=\langle a,b\rangle$. I have to prove that $|G|=8$ if
>
> 1. $|a|=|b|=4$
> 2. $a^2=b^2$
> 3. $ba=a^3 b=a^{-1}b$

$G$ is not abelian. I tried generating all terms of $G$ and then equating some of them, but the number of terms I would have to generate grew extremely rapidly.

I then thought this is equivalent to proving $$\left|\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\langle a^4,b^4,a^2b^{-2},bab^{-1}a^{-3},baba,a^3 b^2 a\rangle}\right|=8$$

Is this assertion correct. Also, how can I go about proving this?

Comment: Hint: Note that the bottom relation allows you to write all words in $a$ and $b$ in the form $a^nb^m$. Now use the other relations to show that you can actually do this with $0\leq n\leq 2$ and $0\leq b\leq 4$ and that elements can be uniquely expressed like this.

Comment: I do not follow your assertion. Because all of the elements on the bottom line are trivial, the group you get is the same as $\langle a, b\rangle$. So although what you say is true, it will not help you...

Comment: If you use the presentation, then the uniqueness part in Tobias' hint is IMHO easier to do by exhibiting a group of order eight together with elements $a,b$ satisfying all the relations. Given a presentation of a group in terms of generators and relations it is often a bit taxing to prove that two elements are not equal to each other. Here you are given the orders of $a$ and $b$, which tells you more than the relations $a^4=1=b^4$ do.

Answer (score 5):

Although my approach is not very common in use, it is a nice way for group presentation. This way is called [Coset enumeration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset_enumeration) or [Todd-Coxeter Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd%E2%80%93Coxeter_algorithm). You have see $8$ rows completed as in the final table. In fact, I found $[G:\langle e\rangle]=8$:
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice one. I think it was the very first algorithm in group theory I was exposed to.

Comment: Nice work, @Babak! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the subgroup $\langle a^2\rangle$. It is normal, and has order two. (Sub-hint: Normal $\Rightarrow$ quotient group...)

Comment: +1 Isn't it $Q_8$?

Comment: @BabakS. Yeah - the subgroup $\langle a^2\rangle$ corresponds to the element $-1=i^2=j^2=k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof consists in showing that all elements of $G$ can be written uniquely in the form
$$
a^{i} b^{j},
$$
with $i \in \{ 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ and $j \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Given any product of $a$ and $b$'s, use relation 3 to bring all $b$ to the far right, and $\lvert a \rvert = 4$ and relation 2 to show you don't need higher exponents. Then use relation 1 and 3 to show that $G$ cannot just be cyclic of order $4$.